# Python. Removing list from another list

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists

```
for i in range(1, 26):
    U.append(i)

A = [8,9,10,11,12,16,17,22,25]
```

How can I extract A values from U list?

Comment: Loop through `A`, calling `U.remove()` with each element.

Comment: What do you mean "extract A values" from the other list? You already have the values in A. Why do you need to extract the same ones from U?

Comment: do you mean you would like a version of the list U without any of the items in A?

Comment: If order isn't important, you can convert them to sets and use subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[item for item in U if item not in A]
```